# PHP preg_match for linux uptime command/reponse

Tags: php, linux

so i am using php to decode up time from Linux commands in a text file

```
:~>uptime
:~>23:20pm  up   1:58,  1 user,  load average: 0.11, 0.09, 0.11
:~>
```

I need 1:58 returned.I have tried:

```
preg_match('/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}/', $a, $b);
```

but get results for "23:20". Additionally "1:58" can grow into a number like "12:34:56" and I need that also.

I struggle so much with expressions. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}[:]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}/
```

This will check if there is another `:00` as part of time, it will get it if not then it will ignore. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3gTygi/1)

**Edit:** Small problem the above regex will also match something like: `12:3342`. So, for that you can use the following regex([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/3gTygi/2)):

```
/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}(?(?=[:]{1})([:]{1}[0-9]{0,2})())/
```

Comment: Tried it but $b[0] is showing the 23:20, but $b[1] is null even with match all

Comment: With `preg_match_all` `$b[0]` will be a multi dimensional array, you can get the values like: `$b[0][1]` etc

Comment: Oh i c its a multi array so $b[0][1]... JINX!

Comment: In the context of the application it is not needed.